# Play Framework and jQuery Ajax request with data as Array

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, playframework

I am sending an Array of values through Ajax via jQuery with a Play Framework backend, and I'm in front of a problem.

Here's an example :

```
$.ajax ({
    'type':     'POST',
    'url':          '/url',
    'timeout':  5000,
    'data':     {'ids': [0, 1, 2, 3]},
    'dataType': 'json',
    'success':  function (oData) {
        // Process ...
    }
});
```

But in Play!, if I do a `params.get("ids");`, I got an empty value, and if I do a `params.getAll("ids");` also.

I know where the problem is, jQuery send the data as : `ids[]=0&ids[]=1&ids[]=2&ids[]=3`
but Play! Framework expect array data to be sent as `ids=0&ids=1&ids=2&ids=3`

Is there a proper way to send the data properly (or get the data as an array in my controller) ?

So far, I managed to make it works simply but creating the request as a String manually in javascript.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you set the data as 'data':  {'ids': 0,'ids': 1,'ids': 2, 'ids': 3}?

Comment: @SKS, have you tried that? You would end up with a map of just { 'ids': 3 } since you are wiping out ids with each map entry.

Comment: @marchaos: True, see my post below.. I was suggesting to write a js function to manually set the query string :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method (leaving your JavaScript code intact) is just declaring your controller method like this:

```
public static void myMethod(@As("ids[]:")List<Long> ids) {
    System.out.println(ids.get(0));
}
```

.. the output is what you expect:

`[0, 1, 2, 3]`

Comment: That's nice! It's just sad there isn't a "natural" way to do it with Play! Maybe I should open a ticket to ask them that. Thanks for that idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's an easier way, but you could just send a string and decode that using [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), i.e:

```
$.ajax ({
    'type':     'POST',
    'url':          '/url',
    'timeout':  5000,
    'data':     {'ids': '[0, 1, 2, 3]'},
    'dataType': 'json',
    'success':  function (oData) {
        // Process ...
    }
});
```

Within your controller, you can convert the string into an array:

```
// data would be "[0, 1, 2, 3]"
int[] intArray = gson.fromJson(data, int[].class);
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me. Give it a try,

```
// Sending request
var params = {
    myArray: [1, 2, 3, 4]
};
var url = '@controllers.routes.AppController.jquery()';
$.post(url, params, function (data) {
    // Process response here
});

// Receiving request
Map<String, String[]> params = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();
Logger.debug("Params : " + params.size());
for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> param : params.entrySet()) {
    Logger.debug(param.getKey() + " = " + param.getValue()[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `traditional: true` to your jQuery.ajax request and the Array will be sent as `ids=0&ids=1&ids=2&ids=3`

```
$.ajax ({
    traditional: true,
    type:        'POST',
    url:         '/url',
    timeout:     5000,
    data:        {'ids': [0, 1, 2, 3]},
    dataType:    'json',
    success:     function (oData) {
        // Process ...
    }
});
```