# How to submit form with multidimensional array in playframework and to pass the variable to controller's action

Tags: forms, variables, playframework, playframework-1.x

I'd like to submit such form:

```
<input type="text" name="features[txt][1]" value="aaa">
<input type="text" name="features[txt][2]" value="bbb">
<input type="text" name="features[num][5]" value="124">
```

and to receive the values in the **save** action:

```
public static void save(Long id, (??) Map<String, String> features) {
    Logger.info("%s", features);
}
```

`Map<String, String> features` - is the most successfull attempt of getting `features` variable. The logger says that it equals **{num=null, txt=null}**. Anyway, `Map<String, String> features` is wrong. I've made alot of another attempts to get `features`, but I just received **null**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, but something along the lines of:

```
public static void save(Long id, @As("ids[][]:") Map<String, String> features) {
    Logger.info("%s", features);
}
```

Something similar has been asked here: [Play Framework and jQuery Ajax request with data as Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855524/play-framework-and-jquery-ajax-request-with-data-as-array/8871755#8871755)

Comment: Thanks, but no. I tried to bind `features` in many different ways. It doesn't work :(