# Accessing returned data from jQuery post to Play Framework

Tags: jquery, post, playframework

I'm trying to access the data returned from an external post function to a Play! project that is running locally. The post is performed locally as well, but from xampp (not Play!) and is successful(seen on server side) - crud is performed and data is returned. I can see the returned data on Opera's DragonFly, on the network tab, under response, however I cannot seem to access it. jQuery does not even get into the `function(data){...}`.

The two methods I used are:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#createTask').click(function(){

        alert('In click function');
        var $title = prompt('Task title');
        var $url = 'http://localhost:9000/application/createtask'

        $.post($url,{title:$title}, function(data){
            alert('In return function');
            //alert(data.title);
            //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }, 'application/json'); 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $url,
            data: {title:$title},
            dataType: "application/json",
            success: function(data){
                alert("Success: " + JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            done: function(data){
                alert("Done: " + JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function (data){
                alert("Error: " + JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        });
    });
})
```

How do I access the returned data? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you execute 2 calls to the same url? Which Play! version? Can you post the code of the `createTask` function?

Comment: Follow this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855524/play-framework-and-jquery-ajax-request-with-data-as-array/43166837#43166837

Answer (score 2):

1. Change `dataType` in `$.ajax({...})` from `"application/json"` to simply `"json"`.
2. jQuery automatically converts JSON data into a JavaScript object when using `"json"` as the `dataType`, so do `console.log(data)` instead of `alert("Success: " + JSON.stringify(data))`.
3. Some of your parameters are not correct.
4. Why the `$` in your variable names?

So try changing your code to the code below.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#createTask').click(function () {
        console.log('In the "click" handler for "#createTask".');

        var task_title  = prompt('Task title', '');
        console.log('Your task will be given the title: "' + task_title + '".');

        var ajax_url    = 'http://localhost:9000/application/createtask';

        $.ajax({
            'complete': function (jqXHR, status) {
                console.log('Complete!');
                console.log(status);
            },
            'data': {
                'title': task_title
            },
            'dataType': 'json',
            'error': function (jqXHR, status, error) {
                console.log('Error!');
                console.log(status);
                console.log(error);
            },
            'success': function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                console.log('Success!');
                console.log(status);
                console.log(data);
            },
            'type': 'POST',
            'url': ajax_url
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: BTW, you might have to use JSONP to resolve cross-domain issues if they come up.

Comment: Thanks! But this does not seem to be working for me. The "error" and "complete" functions are called, but not "success". The response code is "HTTP/1.1 200 OK." Why is success not being called when the response is 200? (I can still see the returned response in Opera, but using `jqXHR.responseText` returns null)

Comment: @LukeLindner Can you try it on Google Chrome or Chromium and take a screenshot of the inspector's console? Upload the screenshot somewhere and comment here with the link. I want to see what happens when all of the JavaScript above is executed. I want to see everything that the console logs. I made a local PHP service that takes the same parameters and this code works fine for me.