# Using jquery with play framework 2.0

Tags: java, jquery, playframework-2.0

I want to use jQuery to open a lightbox but it is causing the problem.
Here is my **Application.java** code:

```
    @(products: List[Products])

    @import helper._

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../public/javascripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../public/javascripts/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

        <!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../public/javascripts/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.0.6"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/stylesheets/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.6" media="screen" />


        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

$('.fancybox').fancybox();

// my code
           });
// rest of the code
```

It gives me the error

**ReferenceError: $ is not defined** showed in firebug.
i even tried changing $ with jQuery but still it doesnt work at all. Also i saw that the jQuery gets loaded in the head section.
Do help me with this.

conf/routes file:

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
#GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)

# Products list (to fetch the list of all the products)
GET     /products                controllers.Application.list

GET     /products/:id           controllers.Application.findAll1(id:Integer)
```

Comment: Follow this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855524/play-framework-and-jquery-ajax-request-with-data-as-array/43166837#43166837

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that your JS paths are wrong.

If you use the default Play config, your Javascript paths should look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/javascripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
...
```

And ever better, using the reverse routing, you should use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("/javascripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")"></script>
...
```

The static assets are provided through a special route defined in your `conf/routes` file:

```
# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

This route simply makes a binding between your local `public` folder and the `/assets` Url.

Comment: The path is correct. I saw the js file even gets loaded in the head section.

Comment: I have added in my question

Comment: Please try my solution, because by looking to your `routes` file, I don't know how it is possible that your JS paths are ok...

Comment: Please take a look at my last edit in order to use the reverse routing ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is the new way to reference assets:

```
@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/jquery-3.1.1.js")
```

More info here:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Assets

Answer (score 0):

here is the simple example of Jquery using ajax in play framework...
Configure the Route 1st

## Routes

## This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)

## ~~~~

## Home page GET    /                controllers.Application.index GET    /newUser         controllers.Application.newUserSign GET       /login

controllers.Application.signInUser  GET    /newUserSignUP
controllers.Application.newUserSignUP1  POST   /newUserSignUP
controllers.Application.newUserSignUP POST  /signIn
controllers.Application.signIn POST   /userDetail
controllers.Application.userDetail GET   /logout
controllers.Application.logout POST   /sendRequest
controllers.Application.sendRequest POST  /friendDetail
controllers.Application.friendList POST  /requestList
controllers.Application.requestList POST  /acceptRequest
controllers.Application.acceptRequest GET   /shwUserDetail 
controllers.Application.shwUserDetail

And the application is as

package controllers

import models.User import play.api._ import play.api.mvc._ import
net.liftweb.json._ import net.liftweb.json.JsonDSL import
net.liftweb.json.Serialization.write import

> scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
>
> object Application extends Controller { implicit val format =
>   DefaultFormats   def index = Action {
>       Ok(views.html.index())   }   def newUserSign = Action {
>       Ok(views.html.newUserSignUpForm())   }   def newUserSignUP = Action { implicit request =>
>       val a = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded
>       val id = a.get("id").head
>       val fnm = a.get("fnm").head
>       val lnm = a.get("lnm").head
>       val email = a.get("email").head
>       val res = a.get("res").head
>       val num = a.get("num").head
>       val pwd = a.get("pwd").head
>
> ```
> val obj = User(id, fnm, lnm, email, res, num, pwd);
> if (models.UserModel.create(obj) > 0) {
>   Ok(views.html.newUserWlcmPage())
> } else {
>   Ok(views.html.Error())
> }
>
> //Ok(" congratulation u r finally registered.. your  id is " + id + "  & your name is => " + fnm + " And you lives in ::" + res)   }   def newUserSignUP1 = Action {
> Ok(views.html.newUserWlcmPage())   }
> def signIn = Action { implicit request =>
> val a = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded
> val id = a.get("id").head
> val pwd = a.get("pwd").head
> val data = models.UserModel.userDetail(id, pwd)
> ```
>
> Redirect(routes.Application.shwUserDetail).withSession("id" -> id)
>
> // Ok(views.html.userInfoPage(data)).withSession("id" -> id)
>          }
>
> def signInUser = Action {  Ok(views.html.login()) }    def
>   shwUserDetail = Action {
>        implicit request =>
>        val id = request.session.get("id").get
>        val usrDetail = models.UserModel.userDetail(id)
>          Ok(views.html.userInfoPage(usrDetail))   }   def userDetail = Action { implicit request =>
>       val b = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded
>       if (!session.get("id").isEmpty) {
>         val id = session.get("id").get
>         //val password = b.get("pwd").head
>
> ```
>   val data = models.UserModel.getAllUserDetail(id)
>   Ok(write(data))
> } else {
>   Ok("")
> }   }   def sendRequest = Action { implicit request =>
> val b = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get
> val receiver_id = b.get("receiver_id").get(0)
> val sender_id = request.session.get("id").get
> val data = models.UserModel.friendRequest(sender_id, receiver_id)
> Ok(write(Map("sucess"->true)))   }   def logout() = Action {
> println("You are successfully logout")
> Ok(views.html.logout()).withNewSession   }   def friendList = Action { implicit request =>   val b = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded
> ```
>
> val sender_id = request.session.get("id").get   val data =
>   models.UserModel.friendList(sender_id)
>
> ```
> Ok(views.html.requestConfirmation())
> ```
>
> }    def requestList = Action { implicit request =>
>           val sender_id = request.session.get("id").get
>       val data = models.UserModel.requestList(sender_id)
>       Ok(write(data))
>
> ```
>   }
> def acceptRequest = Action { implicit request =>
> val b = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get
> val friend_id = b.get("friend_id").get(0)
> val user_id = request.session.get("id").get
> val data = models.UserModel.acceptRequest(friend_id, user_id)
> Ok(write(Map("sucess"->true)))   }    }
> ```
>
> And the mole is as
>
> package models import play.api.db._ import play.api.Play.current
>
> import anorm._ import anorm.SqlParser._
>
> case class User(id: String, fnm: String,lnm: String, email: String,
>   res: String,num: String, pwd: String) case class
>   User1(sender_id:String, receiver_id:String) object UserModel {
>
> def create(obj: User) = {
>
> ```
> DB.withConnection { implicit Connection =>
>
>   val data = SQL("insert into user_detail values({id},{fnm},{lnm},{email},{res},{num},{pwd})").on("id" ->
> ```
>
> obj.id, "fnm" -> obj.fnm, "lnm" -> obj.lnm,"email" -> obj.email,"res"
>   -> obj.res, "num" -> obj.num, "pwd" -> obj.pwd).executeUpdate()
>
> ```
>   data
> }   }   def userDetail(id: String, pwd: String): List[User] = {
> DB.withConnection { implicit Connection =>
>   val dat = SQL("select * from user_detail where id='" + id + "' and pwd='" + pwd +"'")
>   var data = dat().map(row =>
>     User(row[String]("id"),row[String]("fnm"), row[String]("lnm"), row[String]("email"),row[String]("res"),row[String]("num"),row[String]("pwd"))).toList
>   data
> }   }   def userDetail(id: String): List[User] = {
> DB.withConnection { implicit Connection =>
>   val dat = SQL("select * from user_detail where id='" + id + "'")
>   var data = dat().map(row =>
>     User(row[String]("id"),row[String]("fnm"), row[String]("lnm"), row[String]("email"),row[String]("res"),row[String]("num"),row[String]("pwd"))).toList
>   data
> }   }   def friendRequest(sender_id:String,receiver_id:String)={
> DB.withConnection{ implicit c=>
>   val result=SQL("insert into request_table values ({sender_id},{receiver_id})").on("sender_id"->sender_id,"receiver_id"->receiver_id).executeInsert()
>   println("------------------------------------\n"+result);     
>   result
> }
>   }   def getAllUserDetail(id: String) = {
> DB.withConnection { implicit Connection =>
> val dat = SQL("select * from user_detail where id!='" + id +"'")
> var data = dat().map(row =>
>  User(row[String]("id"),row[String]("fnm"), row[String]("lnm"), row[String]("email"),row[String]("res"),row[String]("num"),row[String]("pwd"))).toList
> data
> }    }
>  def friendList(user_id: String) = {
> DB.withConnection { implicit Connection =>
> val dat = SQL("select * from friend_tbl where id!='" + user_id +"'")
> var data = dat().map(row =>
>  User(row[String]("id"),row[String]("fnm"), row[String]("lnm"), row[String]("email"),row[String]("res"),row[String]("num"),row[String]("pwd"))).toList
> data
> }    }   def requestList(sender_id: String) = {
> DB.withConnection { implicit Connection =>
> val dat = SQL("select receiver_id from request_table where sender_id='" + sender_id +"'")
> var data = dat().map(row =>
>  row[String]("receiver_id")).toList
>  data
> }    }   def acceptRequest(friend_id:String, user_id:String)={
> DB.withConnection{ implicit c=
> ```
>
> > Blockquote
>
> ```
>   val result=SQL("insert into friend_tbl values ({friend_id},{user_id})").on("friend_id"->friend_id,"user_id"->user_id).executeInsert()
>   println("------------------------------------\n"+result);     
>   result
> }
>   } }
> ```
>
> and after that configure the view page `enter code here`
>
> ## Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path GET    /assets/*file    controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)

Comment: wtf is this mess... this is helpful to nobody.