# Getting params from JQuery POST in Java Play Framework

Tags: java, jquery, post, playframework, playframework-2.3

I am trying to retrieve params from a POST request with the Java Play Framework (2.3.x).

Here is my post request:

```
$.post(
    "/some/endpoint",
    {
        "thingId": 12345,
        "otherThingId": 1234
    },
    function (data) { /* Do some stuff. */ },
    "json"
);
```

And this is in my controller:

```
public static Result SomeEndpoint() {
    DynamicForm params = Form.form().bindFromRequest();

    System.out.println(params.get("thingId"));
    System.out.println(params.get("otherThingId"));
}
```

Unfortunately, I never get any of the params I am trying to send. Anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at what the browser is sending to the server? You can use your browser dev tools for this. E.g. Firefox dev tools: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor

Comment: Follow this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855524/play-framework-and-jquery-ajax-request-with-data-as-array/43166837#43166837

Answer (score 0):

All I can say is that I am doing the same to extract data out of post.

Did you tried clean compile the project in the sbt command line ?

Do you have a route like this :

```
POST /some/endpoint controllers.MyController.SomeEndpoint()
```